# Scale Instance Has No Attribute '__trunc__'

Tags: tkinter

This is some code that modifies 8 sine wave equations from Tkinter sliders.

The program is supposed to loop the "oscillate" method within the "App" class repeatedly with updated values from the sliders.

I am currently getting the error `Scale Instance Has No Attribute __trunc__'`.

From looking at other questions this error seems to be caused by missing "self", indentation, or data type errors. I think this situation is because of data type errors as I have looked the code over several times and cannot see any typos.

I am unable to see what is going on. The oscillate method worked perfectly fine before I moved it into the class.

The error occurs at the line:

```
pos[0] = (int(self.amp) * math.sin(int(self.afreq)*t)) + 1500 + int(self.f_offset)
```

Which is in the oscillate method near the end of the class "App".

The full error is:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1413, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 498, in callit
    func(*args)
File "Brain.py", line 152, in oscillate
    pos[0] = (int(self.amp) * math.sin(int(self.afreq)*t)) + 1500 + int(self.f_offset)
AttributeError: Scale instance has no attribute '__trunc__'
```

Here is the rest of the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from Tkinter import *
import serial
import time
import math

PI = 3.14159265359

#independant variable for sine waves
t = 0

#time in seconds for oscillators to wait before transmitting current positions
sine_time = 0.05        
elapsed_time = 0

#serial port for botboard communication
bb = serial.Serial('/dev/rfcomm0', 115200)  
print(bb.name)

#start the oscillator timer
start_time = time.time()            

#function to obtain current time
def get_time():                       
  return time.time()


########################################################################################################################
###########################################             GUI            #################################################
########################################################################################################################

class App:
  def __init__(self, master):
    #oscillator control variables
    self.phase = 0                  
    self.afreq = 0                    
    self.amp = 0                    
    self.gait = 0  
    self.knee_amp = 0
    self.gselector = 0

    #front and back joint offsets
    self.fk_offset = 0
    self.bk_offset = 0
    self.f_offset = 0                   
    self.b_offset = 0

    self.frame = Frame(master)
    self.frame.pack()

    #walk button
    self.walk = Button(self.frame, text="Walk")
    self.walk.pack(side=LEFT)
    self.walk.bind("1", self.walk_button)

    #trot button
    self.trot = Button(self.frame, text="Trot")
    self.trot.bind("2", self.trot_button)
    self.trot.pack(side=LEFT)

    #pace button
    self.pace = Button(self.frame, text="Pace")
    self.pace.bind("3", self.pace_button)
    self.pace.pack(side=LEFT)

    #various sliders to control sine waves
    self.phase = Scale(
      master, from_=0, to=3.14, orient=HORIZONTAL, resolution=0.01, sliderlength=50,  length=200, label="Phase", command=self.set_phase)
    self.phase.set(3.14)
    self.phase.pack()

    self.amp = Scale(
      master, from_=0, to=300, orient=HORIZONTAL, sliderlength=50,  length=200, label="Hip Amplitude", command=self.set_amp)
    self.amp.set(150)
    self.amp.pack()

    self.knee_amp = Scale(
      master, from_=0, to=4, orient=HORIZONTAL, sliderlength=50, length=200, resolution=0.01, label= "Knee Amplitude", command=self.set_knee_amp)
    self.knee_amp.set(1)
    self.knee_amp.pack()

    self.afreq = Scale(
      master, from_=0, to=20, orient=HORIZONTAL, sliderlength=50, length=200, label="Angular Frequency", command=self.set_afreq)
    self.afreq.set(1)
    self.afreq.pack()

    self.fkoffset = Scale(
      master, from_=-400, to=400, orient=HORIZONTAL, sliderlength=50, length=200, label="Front Knee Offset", command=self.set_fkoffset)
    self.fkoffset.set(0)
    self.fkoffset.pack()

    self.bkoffset = Scale(
      master, from_=-400, to=400, orient=HORIZONTAL, sliderlength=50, length=200, label="Back Knee Offset", command=self.set_bkoffset)
    self.bkoffset.set(0)
    self.bkoffset.pack()

    self.foffset = Scale(
      master, from_=-400, to=400, orient=HORIZONTAL, sliderlength=50, length=200, label="Front Offset", command=self.set_foffset)
    self.foffset.set(232)
    self.foffset.pack()

    self.boffset = Scale(
      master, from_=-400, to=400, orient=HORIZONTAL, sliderlength=50, length=200, label="Rear Offset", command=self.set_boffset)
    self.boffset.set(108)
    self.boffset.pack()

  #change "gait" variable based on button selected from the gui
  def walk_button(self, event):
    self.gait = PI/2

  def trot_button(self, event):
    self.gait = -PI

  def pace_button(self, event):
    self.gait = 0

  #functions to obtain values returned from gui sliders
  def set_phase(self, event):
    self.phase = event

  def set_amp(self, event):
    self.amp = event

  def set_afreq(self, event):
    self.afreq = event

  def set_fkoffset(self, event):
    self.fk_offset = event

  def set_bkoffset(self, event):
    self.bk_offset = event

  def set_foffset(self, event):
    self.f_offset = event

  def set_boffset(self, event):
    self.b_offset = event

  def set_knee_amp(self, event):
    self.knee_amp = event

  def oscillate(self):
    #variables for timer, will be added to the class soon
    global t, start_time, elapsed_time

    #array to hold the servo positions
    #positions = [SB,SF,HB,HF,EB,EF,KB,KF]
    pos = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

    #sine waves generate servo positions for each joint of the robot
    pos[0] = (int(self.amp) * math.sin(int(self.afreq)*t)) + 1500 + int(self.f_offset)
    pos[1] = (int(self.amp) * math.sin(int(self.afreq)*t)) + 1522 - int(self.f_offset)
    pos[2] = (int(self.amp) * math.sin(int(self.afreq)*t + gait)) + 1500 + int(self.b_offset)
    pos[3] = (int(self.amp) * math.sin(int(self.afreq)*t + gait)) + 1446 - int(self.b_offset)

    pos[4] = (int(self.amp)*float(self.knee_amp) * math.sin(int(self.afreq)*t + float(self.phase))) + 1500 + int(self.fk_offset)
    pos[5] = (int(self.amp)*float(self.knee_amp) * math.sin(int(self.afreq)*t + float(self.phase))) + 1581 - int(self.fk_offset)
    pos[6] = (int(self.amp)*float(self.knee_amp) * math.sin(int(self.afreq)*t + gait + float(self.phase))) + 1500 + int(self.bk_offset)
    pos[7] = (int(self.amp)*float(self.knee_amp) * math.sin(int(self.afreq)*t + gait + float(self.phase))) + 1538 - int(self.bk_offset)

    #get current time
    elapsed_time = get_time()

    if (elapsed_time - start_time >= sine_time):
       print ('time difference: %s' % (elapsed_time - start_time))
       start_time = elapsed_time
       t += 1

       #format servo positions properly
       for i in range(len(pos)):
         if (pos[i] < 1000):
       pos[i] = '0' + str(int(pos[i]))

         else:
       pos[i] = str(int(pos[i]))

       #transmit servo positions over serial connection
       #bb.write('%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d\n' % (SB,SF,HB,HF,EB,EF,KB,KF))
       print('%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s\n' % (pos[0],pos[1],pos[2],pos[3],pos[4],pos[5],pos[6],pos[7]))
       bb.write('%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s\n' % (pos[0],pos[1],pos[2],pos[3],pos[4],pos[5],pos[6],pos[7]))

    root.after(int(sine_time*1000),self.oscillate)


#########################################################################################################################
#######################################               MAIN PROGRAM             ##########################################
#########################################################################################################################

root = Tk()

app = App(root)

root.after(0,app.oscillate)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start by defining `self.phase` as the value zero, then you change it to an instance of `Scale`, and later you set it to an event object, but you're using it in an expression as if it's still an integer.

The solution is to not use the same variable for multiple purposes.